# Azure Worker Role - Threading, memory consumption, fragmentation and compaction

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure, task-parallel-library, azure-worker-roles

Our running Cloud Service role makes an intensive use of threading. It spins up more and less 100 Tasks. Most of them do something, then they sleep for some minutes than start again. Some of them spin up a Service Bus Queue Client and handle up to 5 concurrent messages. Those services do a lot of stuff, but mainly data trasformation: they takes something from the DB and send them to external web services, or they take something from those web services and put on the DB.

From my application's service inventory, I'd say that there are no more than 300 "concurrent" Tasks.

Because of some error logs, I had to try to go deeper and I found something strange. I try to sum up what I discovered and what I think about them. I'd be glad to get a check from you.

This application is a .NET 4.5.2 worker role, compiled for a 64-bit architecture, and runs on a 2 Standard_A2 Medium Instances (i.e. 3.5GB memory, 2 core CPU). Because of the usage of Redis Caching, we have tweaked the ThreadPool SetMinThread like this:

`ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(300, 300);`

Now, here is what I discovered going through my analysis:

1. It happens that I log this error: "There were not enough free threads in the ThreadPool to complete the operation."

I think this is related to async / await operations in our whole application. If I understood correctly, async/await should use IO Completion Ports part of the Thread Pool. The fact that there are no free IOCP, sent me through the need of raising up accordingly the "SetMaxThread" property of the ThreadPool. Does it make sense?

```
int CurrentMaxWorkerThreads = 0;
int CurrentMaxIOPorts = 0;
ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out CurrentMaxWorkerThreads, out CurrentMaxIOPorts);
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(CurrentMaxWorkerThreads, 4000);
```

2. Memory usage: I've seen that after some days of running  (2-3 days), the process takes more and less 2GB. Using Ants Memory Profiler, I discovered that a lot of this used memory is free, because fragmented (I'll ask about this on point 3). The question is: shouldn't my application scale up to more than 2GB? Isn't the 2GB limit set just for 32 bit applications?
3. Memory fragmentation: I've read a lot about that in those days, and I really think that trying to figure out why it's happening will be very time expensive, even because - using Ants Memory Profiler - I see that a lot of memory consumption is due to byte arrays (that probably are generated to send stuff outside of the application). Right now, just to keep things under control, I'd compact the LOH, using the .NET 4.5.1 feature:

`GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce; 
GC.Collect();`

Comment: It's really hard to say what's exactly went wrong without some actual code. The error about the `MinThreads` is about threads, not IOPorts. It looks like your Azure app is limited with simultaneous threads. I/O operations [are not using a thread to wait for an operation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html), so the problem is in your code. Also consider use a shared buffer for your operations instead of new array byte creation with garbage collection hacks.

Comment: Which error about MinThreads? Are you talking about #1? Thanks for the article, where I already fell into, but I think that using async / await, as soon as the operation completes isn't a new thread created?

Comment: No, these is compiled into TPL usage, so not a thread, but a task.